# Adding Numeric Value in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML and Java Script. I am setting to display the Total amount of these 3 input field automatically. But it gaves me wrong answer if I use + (adding). I works well if I use * (multiply) or / (devide.) Any one please Help!

Here's my HTML code.

```
</pre>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='number' id='amt1' name='amt1' onkeyup='total_amount();' onKeyUp='return numbersonly(event);' class='form-control'></td>
        <td><input type='number' id='amt2' name='amt2' onkeyup='total_amount();' onKeyUp='return numbersonly(event);' class='form-control'></td>
        <td><input type='number' id='amt3' name='amt3' onkeyup='total_amount();' onKeyUp='return numbersonly(event);' class='form-control'></td>
        <td><input type='number' id='total' name='total' class='form-control' readonly='readonly'></td>
    </tr>
<pre>
```

Heres my Java Script...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function total_amount()
    {
        document.getElementById('total').value = document.getElementById('amt1').value + document.getElementById('amt2').value + document.getElementById('amt3').value
    }

    function numbersonly(e){
       var unicode=e.charCode? e.charCode : e.keyCode
       if (unicode!=8 && unicode!=46 && unicode!=37 && unicode!=27 && unicode!=38 && unicode!=39 && unicode!=40 && unicode!=9){ //if the key isn't the backspace key (which we should allow)
           if (unicode<48||unicode>57)
               return false
        }
    }

</script>
</pre>
```

Comment: Why does `"1" + "1" == "11"`? Oh, you're adding strings…

Comment: Limiting user input to certain keys is not user friendly, and doesn't stop entry of non–digits via pasting or other means, just don't do it. You only care what the value is after the user has finished inputting it, how they got there is up to them.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple. Use [event delegation](http://icant.co.uk/sandbox/eventdelegation/) and one keyUp handler. Don't use inline handlers. Convert the field value to `Number` before your do calculations with it. Here's an example:

```js
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('keyup', sum);

function sum(e) {
  var from = e.target || e.srcElement
     ,isNumericInput = /number/i.test(from.type);
  if (!isNumericInput) {return true;}
  var d = document
     ,inputs = d.querySelector('table').querySelectorAll('[type=number]')
     ,sumfld = d.querySelector('#sum')
     ,sumnow = 0;
  
  [].forEach.call(inputs,
                  function (v) {
                      sumnow += +(v.value); //<= conversion to Number, using +
                   });
  
  sumfld.textContent = sumnow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <td><input type='number' id='amt1' name='amt1' class='form-control'></td>
   <td><input type='number' id='amt2' name='amt2' class='form-control'></td>
   <td><input type='number' id='amt3' name='amt3' class='form-control'></td>
   <td><b>Total</b>: <span id="sum"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: where should i put these?

`document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('keyup', sum);`

these should be included in my script function?

Comment: @JohnArzaga at the top of your script, or within an `onload` handler

Comment: @RobG, sure. It's no showstopper I'd say, but removed the `|| 0` part.

Comment: something like `<table onload='document.querySelector('table')>` or `<body onload=` ??

Comment: @JohnArzaga 1. `window.onload = function (){ document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('keyup', sum) };`  
2. place the `<script>...</script>` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag and place the handler assignment as first line within the script.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
document.getElementById('amt1').value|0 +
document.getElementById('amt2').value|0 +
document.getElementById('amt3').value|0 ;
```

OR

```
parseInt(document.getElementById('amt1').value) +
parseInt(document.getElementById('amt2').value) +
parseInt(document.getElementById('amt3').value) ;
```

so that these considered as number

Comment: Code only answers aren't liked, explain the OPs issue and why your answer fixes it. `|0` is not a good strategy if the OP is using floats.

Comment: parseInt should be used. but it does not allow text box to be empty. you should enter 0.

Comment: then put check of empty text box. If textbox is empty, either use 0 or not parse the string.

Comment: i want my textbox to look clean. 0 should not appear if one of the amount is empty.

Comment: do not write 0 inside text box just use it for your calculation

Answer (score 1):

change your function

```
function total_amount() {
    var amt1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('amt1').value);
    if (isNaN(amt1)) {
        amt1 = 0;
    }

    var amt2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('amt2').value);
    if (isNaN(amt2)) {
        amt2 = 0;
    }

    var amt3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('amt3').value);
    if (isNaN(amt3)) {
        amt3 = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById('total').value = amt1 + amt2 + amt3;
}
```

Comment: than don't forget to right mark. so it'll help others.

Answer (score 1):

use `parseInt()`.

```
function total_amount()
{
    document.getElementById('total').value =parseInt( document.getElementById('amt1').value) +   
parseInt(document.getElementById('amt2').value) + parseInt(document.getElementById('amt3').value)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for converting a string (returned by .value) to a number is to use the unary `+` operator:

```
function total_amount() { 
    document.getElementById('total').value = 
        +document.getElementById('amt1').value + 
        +document.getElementById('amt2').value + 
        +document.getElementById('amt3').value 
}
```